# choose a member of the coset?

Tags: group-theory

If  H  is the subgroup of  $S_4$ genereated by $(12)(34)$.then which of the following is  a member of the coset$ H(123)$   ?

a).(1 3 2)

b) (1 3 4)

c) (1 2 4)

d) (2 4 3)

i thinks  it will option d)

Comment: Hint: The element you are looking for is the product $(12)(34)\cdot(123)$. Why? (Also, order does not really matter - every element is in *some* coast, or order cannot matter...)

Comment: All you need to do is calculate $(1\,2)(3\,4)(1\,2\,3)$.

Comment: i got( 2 4 3) is  its correct  @user1729

Comment: Well, that is not on the list!

Comment: thanks@user1729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subgroup $H$ has two elements: $H=\{id,(12)(34)\}$. Thus it's easy to compute $H(123)=\{(123),(12)(34)(123)\}$.

Now, if you use standard function composition, that is, $fg(x)=f(g(x))$,
$$
(12)(34) (123) =(243)
$$
If you use reverse function composition, that is, $(x)fg=((x)f)g$,
$$
(12)(34) (123) =(134)
$$
So the answer depends on what convention you use for composition of functions.

Comment: thanks@egreg....

Comment: Surely $H(123) = \{(123), (12)(34)(123) \}$?

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks, I seem to have problems in distinguishing the right from the left lately.